# For a 6-character number, how many different numbers can be made using hexadecimals?

Tags: combinatorics

I have always been curious about this as an aviation enthusiast. Using hexadecimal numbers **000000-ffffff**, how many different numbers are there in this range including the first and last numbers?  Would I be wrong to think the result would be **16x16x16x16x16x16** for all the permutations?

Comment: You are correct, the answer is $16^6$

Comment: In hexadecimal, FFFFFF represents the number $2^{24}-1=16777215$.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the first digit in $16$ ways.

*For each* of those choices, you have $16$ choices for the second digit, so the total number of choices for the first two digits is $16\times16=16^2$.

*For each* of those choices for the first two digits, you have $16$ choices for the third digit, so the total number of choices for the first *three* digits is $16^2\times16=16^3$.

And so on.

Following the same logic a few more times, we conclude that the total number of choices of *all* six digits is $16^6$.

You can generalise: if you have an alphabet of $k$ symbols, and you are trying to see how many words of length $n$ you can make out of them, the answer is $k^n$.

Comment: Many  thanks for reply. It was very helpful.